# (How to Think like a Computer Scientist - 6.3 Unit Testing) Unit Testing using test vs unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

The sample code in the book uses the test module shown here:

```
def square(x):
    '''raise x to the second power'''
    return x * x

import test
print('testing square function')
test.testEqual(square(10), 100)
```

However, when I write out the script and use IDLE to run it I get the following error:

```
testing square function
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ivan/Documents/scripts/Untitled.py", line 7, in <module>
    test.testEqual(square(10), 100)
AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'testEqual'
```

Checking the Global Module Index > test module shows that the preferred method is to use the unittest module. Here is the given example:

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            s.split(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The problem is that we have not learned anything past import unittest as seen in this example.

Is there a way to use the unittest module as given in the first script in this question?

Comment: I don't really understand your question... what is `test`???

Comment: I can't get your first script to work, and I don't see how your error message relates to it.

Comment: Note, your error message doesn't seem consistent with what you've posted... `unittest.square(10), 100` ...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My mistake! I have pasted in the correct error code.

Comment: @quamrana I pasted the incorrect error message and have edited it to show the related one.

Comment: ... OK, but you still haven't told us what is `test`??? Why do you expect it to have a `'testEqual'` method???

Comment: I think you need a better book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the python book has its own simplified unit testing under the **test** module.
if you want to create such a simple testing you can create a function like below and call that function.

`def testEqual(x,y):
    if x==y:
        print('Passed')
    else:
        print('Failed')
testEqual(square(10), 100)`

Comment: I figured this out way later! Thank you for the response :)